# ubuntu 22.04 Intel AX210 can't capture the Wi-Fi packets under monitor it seems there's a Wi-Fi crash

Tags: networking

I would like to use Intel AX210 to capture the Wi-Fi packets.
But, the Wireshark always told me "No packets captured".

I'm pretty sure the Wi-Fi adapter is under monitor mode.
I can use the same way on the other laptop to do the same thing.

Then, I accidentally saw the dmesg pop-up Wi-Fi crash messages after I enable the Wi-Fi adapter with monitor mode.

Is there a way to fix this issue? I never met the situation before.
Thanks.

[image: 01_Linux_release_version]
[image: 02_Intel_AX210_FW]
[image: 03_Call Trace]

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question.There are many reasons for this, one is pictures can not be searched and are harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the URL below, where I solved this problem.

ubuntu 22.04 Intel AX210 can't capture the Wi-Fi pkts under monitor it seems there's a Wi-Fi crash
https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/ubuntu-22-04-Intel-AX210-can-t-capture-the-Wi-Fi-pkts-under/m-p/1425413#M43830